# Responsive columns with remaining viewport's height under a navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, flexbox

I have a non-fixed navbar and two columns. With a desktop layout there is no problem, but when I test the responsiveness from a mobile screen size, I need the column A to fill the remaining viewport's height and the column B to go under the column A. In addition, I need a solution that doesn't involve hardcoding, like subtracting the navbar's height. I've tried using Flexbox, but I haven't made it work. Instead, what I get is that both columns appear in the viewport. I'm using Bootstrap for the responsiveness.

[Here there is a figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvH6J.png) that shows my problem. Here is the code I've tried so far:

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#content {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

#row {
    flex-grow: 1; max-width: 100vw;
}

#col1 {
    background-color: dimgrey;color: white;
}

#col2 {
    background-color:darkslategrey;color: white
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Web title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="vh-100 flex-container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container px-0">
          <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Navbar title</span>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div id="content" class="container flex-container px-0">
          <div id="row" class="row mx-0">
            <div id="col1" class="col-sm px-0">
              Column 1 content
            </div>
            <div id="col2" class="col-sm px-0">
              Column 2 content
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post the code you've attempted so far

Comment: @Zim Code posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your question I understood that you want the first child to take full height and then a second child should appear after scrolling through the first child.

As your content is set to `flex: 1` which is by default taking entire remaining height, you can use it for your advantage here, now set `#row` and its children height to 100% as follows

```
#row, #row > * {
    height: 100%
}
```

This will help you to set the height of `#row` and its children to at 100%.
So it will give you the desired result while in the mobile layout.

I hope this solves your query.

Comment: That was similar to what I was asking but not exactly. What I need is the column A to fill the remaining viewport, not to be as the same height of the viewport. In other words, I need the column A to have the viewport's height minus the navbar's height, but without using any subtraction operation. Your suggestion makes the column A to acquire the entire height of the viewport, which causes a portion of the column A to be hidden and to exceed the viewport. I hope I have explained clearly, if not, just ask me again :)

Comment: There is a solution for that too, using `min-height: calc(100vh - 40px - 1em)`, content height is `40px`, and padding is `0.5em` for both top and bottom of the content that's why `1em`, which will probably solve your issue and column A will acquire the remaining height of the viewport. But, it seems you don't want to make any calculations. May I know why?

Comment: The reason I don't want to use hardcoded calculations is because there are harder to maintain in the future. That's why I was wondering if there is any workaround to my problem avoiding this kind of calculations.

Comment: Okay, I got your concern, so you can set `height: 100%` to `#row` and to its children which will also solve your issue and you don't have to use `calc()` for that. I have also updated code in the above answer, please have a look at it too! I think this will definitely solve your query.

Comment: That is what I was looking for :) thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use a media query to only set height 100vh on the smallest screen widths ...

```
@media (max-width: 576px) {
    .min-100 {
        min-height: 100vh;
    }
}
```

https://codeply.com/p/1zHDI4rsc8

Comment: Maybe my explanation was not very clear. Please read the comments of Prathamesh Koshti's answer because they apply the same way to your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is a responsive design. 
You could use MediaQueri to limit what you see in different sizes. 
And for that functionality you want to do if you are using boostrap the best thing you can do would be to use the carousel.

Visit  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/carousel/ to see how the carrousel works

Comment: I've updated the figure for clarity. I don't see how the carrousel could help me. In the mobile layout, the columns are supposed to be located one under the other, not alongside. Besides, the problem of the viewport thing is still there.